# Wordpress page not found error for posts with hyphen in permalink

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need some help related to permalinks.

I have two custom post types "books" and "authors"(created using CPT UI plugin).

i have created few authors where the permalink is generated as "http://wordpressproject.localhost/author/sagar-kumar-boina",(with hyphens). This pages are giving page not found error.

But the books with hyphen in permalinks are working fine. (http://wordpressproject.localhost/book/be-with-me)

I'm trying since 2 days. can you plase help me to solve this.

Thanks,
Sagar.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried following the instructions on the plugin's FAQ page?  He states:

> I receive a 404 error when viewing custom post type content
>
> This is usually caused if the rewrite slug was changed. To fix this
>   issue simply visit Settings > Permalinks to flush the rewrite rules in
>   WordPress

It's pretty vague on what you've tried to do in an attempt to fix this already, so I apologize in advance if you've already tried it.  If this doesn't work, please give more details.  The hyphens have nothing to do with this issue.